# Extracting numbers from a text file except numbers in specific context

Tags: python, regex, text

I am trying to extract all the numbers in a text file ***except*** the numbers from the ***date*** and the ***Total change***. I currently have this regex `pattern = re.compile(r'[-]?\d+[,]?\d+?')` which extracts all the numbers. Can anybody suggest how to put exceptions in it.

My text file

```
Changes from:       August 18, 2020                                  Total Change is:    -3,029

         0     -2,872        -18        898        870       -200     -2,819       -311       -112          0          2          0       -778       -388
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the unwelcome strings and match and *capture* the numbers in all other contexts using the *best regex trick ever*:

```
results = [x for x in re.findall(r'Total Change is:\s*\S+|Changes from:.*?\d{4}\b|([-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?)', text) if x]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBvczI/1/). Regex details:

- `Total Change is:\s*\S+` - `Total Change is:`, zero or more whitespaces, one or more non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `Changes from:.*?\d{4}\b` - `Changes from:`, zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, four digits and a word boundary after
- `|` - or
- `([-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Group 1 (`re.findall` returns these values only): an optional `+` or `-`, one or more digits, and then an optional sequence of a comma and one or more digits

After you get the results with `re.findall`, you will just need to remove empty items from the result list.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/deoQIQ):

```
import re
rx = r"Total Change is:\s*\S+|Changes from:.*?\d{4}\b|([-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?)"
text = "Changes from:       August 18, 2020                                  Total Change is:    -3,029\n\n        0     -2,872        -18        898        870       -200     -2,819       -311       -112          0          2          0       -778       -388"
results = [x for x in re.findall(r'Total Change is:\s*\S+|Changes from:.*?\d{4}\b|([-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?)', text) if x]
print(results)
# => ['0', '-2,872', '-18', '898', '870', '-200', '-2,819', '-311', '-112', '0', '2', '0', '-778', '-388']
```